# Android BLE BluetoothGattCharacteristic writing additional values

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to write a command to a BluetoothGattCharacteristic with a parameter on it. I know how to write a command in bytes by setValue() method. But do not know how to write the parameter.

Comment: Do you mean how to write a value and perform a WriteCharacteristic of it to a remote device ?.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to perform a BLE write:

```
public void writeValue(final String uuid, final byte[] value)
{
    final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = getCharacteristic(bluetoothGatt, uuid);
    characteristic.setValue(value);
    bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
}
```

The first argument of the method is a specified characteristic UUID of a service in your remote device
you want to access. The second argument is a byte Array you want to write to the characteristics of the remote device.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know anything about how to write a message body to the characteristic?

Comment: That's not possible as far as I know. Remember that you can maximum send 20 Bytes at a time over BLE interface. However, you can still include the message you want to send inside the byte Array, by declaring the first two elements to the value, and the rest 18 elements as the message. In this case, you have to program the microcontroller of your remote device in a way, that is should seperate both values from each other, whenever it receives a value from your central device.